# Sheet name from Sheet Code

Tags: excel, vba

anyone knows how to get the sheet name from the VBA code on that sheet? i.e. : the code on sheet12 will return name of Sheet12, same code on sheet11 will return name of Sheet11? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are two properties you can refer to:

1. `.Name`: This is the name of the worksheet that you can see in the Excel UI
2. `.CodeName`: This is the name of the worksheet that you see in the VB editor

Example:

```
MsgBox "Name of the current sheet in Excel: " & ActiveSheet.Name & vbCrLf & _
    "Name of the sheet in VB editor: " & ActiveSheet.CodeName
```

Comment: thanks - but the ActiveSheet will not necessarily be the sheet which code has been activated. My problem is that Excel often triggers executions through the code of other sheets - even with Calculation Set to Manual, and some (not all) code on those sheets needs to be protected from these executions. Ideally, the function/property will return the name of the sheet from which it is called. Thanks

Comment: Not sure there is something that you can use all the time. Depending on the situation, `Application.Caller`will give you the information (e.g. when called by a button). If it's triggered by an event, often the event contains the information (e.g. in `Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`, `sh.Name` will be what you want). for all other situation, please provide and example!

Answer (score 2):

This will give the name of whichever sheet is active:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```